# Is thery any light weight text editor like notepad++ but with text colors

Tags: windows-7, text-editors

I use notepad ++ in windows 7 but i can't color the text.
Is there any lightweight editor like notepadd++ where i can also color the text as well

Comment: I only see this when I create a new document and i have not saved it yet. If you do a save as it should begin detecting the type of file you are working with highlighting as it goes.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called [Syntax Highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting), and notepad ++ supports it. I'd also add that questions asking for 'lists' of software will probably get closed. Considering that your editor of choice supports it, and it isn't working, consider asking a question relating to the specific sort of language you're working on and getting notepad++ to do it.

Comment: But if use syntax highlight in notepadd ++ , it apply that to whole documwnt. But i want to slect one paragraph and then apply c++ highlight and in other para of same doc apply java highlight

Answer (score 1):

Who says Notepad++ does not allow you to modify the text colour, background colour, font, font style etc.? Just go to `Settings / Style Configurator` and you can either set global or per language (file type) styles:

[image]

Comment: Can i just select the text of one line and then chnage its color

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible.